# In the Duckverse, do we ever see any other creature besides Scrooge successfully swim in money?

Tags: ducktales

Over [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174146/how-can-scrooge-mcduck-dive-into-money-without-hurting-himself) we see that Scrooge has a pretty unique skill that he can swim through money.

In the entire Duckverse (Ducktales, Barks, etc.), do we ever see anyone else with this skill?

Comment: Hmmmmmmm. The original comic where we are introduced to Flintheart Glomgold, he also bathed in his money and has a very, very similar money bin. I don't know that we see him swimming in the money tho

Comment: Yup, just checked my memories and "The Second Richest Duck in the World" shows Flintheart (a South African diamond mogul) being more or less identical to Scrooge. He bathes in money and has a money bin. Buuuuut no, we don't directly see him actually swim in it.

Comment: Didn't Huey, Duey and Louie also swim in Scrooge's bin in the cartoon a couple dozen years ago?

Comment: Huey, Duey, Louie and Donald Duck: multiple times. Huey, Duey and Louie have shown to have the same capability as Scrooge to jump into the money. Donald Duck cannot, but -along with the aforementioned three- has been shown many times to dive in the depth of the Money Bin for maintenance purpose. The Beagle Boys have been shown once to be able to jump and swim.

Comment: @motoDrizzt the Beagle Boys can swim? where?

Comment: @TheAsh: well, that's the reason this is a comment and not an answer. I have decent memory of Disney stories, but I don't remember the specific comic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the new Ducktales, Season 1, Episode 23 "The Shadow War" shows the characters swimming in the money bin with varying degrees of success.

From [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ducktales/comments/98px04/spoiler_s01e23_golden_money_swimming_gag/):

> Huey, Dewey and Webby swam on top of it, Donald Duck hurt his butt on
>   the surface trying to do a cannon ball, Launchpad got stuck head first
>   and the rest were just sitting/walking on top of it all.

A clip is available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4WDGKX19hs).

And screen shot (from the same Reddit):
[image: Scrooge and Louie swimming in money]

Answer (score 8):

There was a Carl Barks comic in which Magica de Spell, having magically swindled Scrooge out of his hoard (as she often tried to do), was able to swim/move through the sea of cash.  Her capacity can probably be attributed to magic, obviously.

Comment: I remember a comic, maybe the same of you, where they sailed over a stormy sea of coins to get the first one from the bottom of a maelstrom to undo the spell

Comment: Can you confirm *which* comic this happened in?